# How to check matching id in variables with data in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

```
$user_id = '2';
```

In my database having one column with values like `'2,3,5'`. I just need to check whether the `$user_id` value is that column. Is there any easy way to check it?

Comment: use find_in_set

Comment: Yes. Normalise your schema

Comment: Multiple rows in that column is there. Then query will be like "SELECT id FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET($user_id,column_name)". Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `@Devsi Odedra`, you can use `find_in_set`  as:

```
SELECT *FROM table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET($user_id,user_id) <> 0
```

Please read about [find_in_set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Or you can also use `like Operator` as:

```
SELECT *FROM table_name WHERE CONCAT(",",user_id, ",") LIKE '%,$user_id,%';
```